# How to create a database in the device native platform using Worklight?

Tags: android, sqlite, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am Using Worklight 6.0 to create a cross platform Application. I want to create a DB in Android(SQLlite) to store my app data so that everytime I do not have to connect to the Worklight Server to retrieve my App Data.

Say an image of my company has to be stored in the local directory so that next time I load my application it has check only if the data is modified, if not then, display the image directly from the local directory.

Comment: What are you talking about? What is this "app data"? Explain the FULL SCENARIO you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your use case is, but storing data locally is exactly what [JSONStore](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_overview.html) does.  And it's cross-platform, so you don't have to worry about reimplementing native functionality on each type of device you want your application to run on.

Comment: Can we store images using JSONStore?

Comment: The JSONStore allows you to store collections of documents; it doesn't place any limitations on what those documents can be.  You can store anything you can express as JSON data.  Check the documentation I linked above for more information.